# How to replace single quotes within a string with quoted double quotes

Tags: python, string

For example:

Input:

```
{'match_all':{}}
```

Output:

```
{'"match_all"':{}}
```

Is there some regex that can do this?

I know I could iterate through the string and whenever I encounter a key replace each side of it with ‘“ followed by “‘; however, I was wondering if any of you knew a more pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Creating a command line elastic search utility program for some co-workers. When copying queries from elastic search, the keys are singly quoted. However, when loading JSON using the json library, it requires the keys to be surrounded by both double and single quotes.

Comment: Are you trying to get a string that is in two sets of quotes? Or just change the representation of strings in your REPL?

Comment: I want to prevent users of the REPL from having to manually replace each single quote with a double and single quote before running the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not try using this method: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm and try to replace, ' for '" and the second ' for "'...

```
str = "this is string example....wow!!! this is really string"
print str.replace("is", "was")
print str.replace("is", "was", 3)
```

the output returns:

> thwas was string example....wow!!! thwas was really string
>
> thwas was string example....wow!!! thwas is really string

```
print str.replace("'", "'"")
print str.replace("'", ""'", 1)
```

use ' " as needed to avoid errors...

Comment: I don’t think this would work. If I replaced the single quotes with ‘“ and then did it again but set the max to 1, it would skip the first one, but if my json was any longer, I would be stuck. It would need to flip back and forth. Unless I’m interpreting this wrong, max(the third argument) does not do this correct?

Comment: You could possibly try using a bool or int i and set to first char and for second, you can also use this function to check for chars in string and then switch out char at 0 and 1...    $' in s   to return if it finds a " or ' or what not, anyhow good luck i hope you find your answer or these functions come of some use.

Comment: It ended up that my string didn't even have quotes in it to begin with, so I'm unable to do anything about it. Thanks though.